# GSoap client can not pass argument value to server

Tags: c, web-services, gsoap

step 1, i had create an WebService using ASP.NET (C#):

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    public class WebService1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        [WebMethod]
        public string HelloWorld(int a, int b)
        {
            return a.ToString() + "," + b.ToString();
        }
    }
```

step 2, and then i use gsoap_2.8.12 generate code, following command:

```
 wsdl2h -c -o a.h http://localhost:29556/WebService1.asmx?WSDL
  soapcpp2 -c -C -I import a.h
```

step3, create an empty C project in VC, add the following files:
    soapH.h
    soapStub.h
    stdsoap2.h
    soapC.c
    soapClient.c
    stdsoap2.c

step4, config the folders, and create a new class :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "WebService1Soap.nsmap";

void main()
{
    struct soap soap;
    int ret;
    struct _ns1__HelloWorld hello;
    struct _ns1__HelloWorldResponse respHello;
    int arg1, arg2;

    soap_init(&soap);
    hello.a = 2;
    hello.b = 3;

    ret = soap_call___ns1__HelloWorld(&soap, NULL, NULL, &hello, &respHello);
    if (ret == SOAP_OK)
    {
        printf("return :%s", respHello.HelloWorldResult);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("error :%d", ret);
    }

    getchar();
}
```

Problem: the return value is "0,0", as we expect it should be "2,3", 
Please tell me what i had missed about these things ? thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after hours work, i had fixed this thing, if you are using WCF , you need add an attribute into your operation, for example:

```
[ServiceContract]
    public interface IMyService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [XmlSerializerFormat(Style = OperationFormatStyle.Rpc, Use = OperationFormatUse.Literal)]
        long Method1(int a, int b, long c, string d);
     }
```

if using WebService, that should be:

```
[WebMethod]
        [System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapRpcMethodAttribute(Use = System.Web.Services.Description.SoapBindingUse.Literal)]
        public string HelloWorld(int a, int b)
        {
            return a.ToString() + "," + b.ToString();
        }
```

so the gsoap can send the argument value correctly to server.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issue when service receives arguments as 0s, as a result it return 0. Hope this helps you.    [gsoap2.8 client and wcf service()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13980633/gsoap2-8-client-and-wcf-service)

Comment: Great. Thank you timiil. Using your XmlSerializerFormat(...) I am back to gSOAP version 2.8.12_2 without problem, RPC is good for me